# How do I replace Berryboot boot partition with a regular one?

Tags: boot, partition, berryboot

I no longer need the option to boot different operating systems and want to overcome Berryboot's firmware/kernel update limitations.

Could I simply replace the current FAT boot partition with a regular/vanilla one?

Comment: You may be able to. Make a backup of your SD card so if you make any mistake you can revert back to the original. Sorry I can't say if this works differently. Thats because I don't use berryboot myself. Just that this may help you to seed up finding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. I set up a blank SD card with proper partitions using gparted. I copied the boot files from another Pi 2 to the boot partition, I booted my berryboot setup with the new SD card in a card reader in one of the USB ports. I copied (`cp -pdRx`) the running OS partition to the blank one (`rsync` would have worked as well).

I only had to enter the proper network settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I ran into some minor problems which stemmed from having run `rpi-update` before and thus having created an inconsistent setup (rpi-update cannot really write to the boot partition in a berryboot setup). Running `rpi-update` again in the new non-berryboot environment fixed this